# in active_admin, skip_before_filter for authentication is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin, before-filter

I am trying to use activeadmin to make the entire site, not just the admin dashboard.  I have changed the `admin_user` to `facility_user`.  For the facility user page, i want to skip authentication so that anyone who comes to the site can register as a facility_user.  Here is my active_admin code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register FacilityUser do
    permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    controller do
        skip_before_filter :authenticate_facility_user!
    end
end
```

And here is the relevant part of the activeadmin initializer:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
    config.default_namespace = :facility_users
    config.authentication_method = :authenticate_facility_user!
end
```

However, this is not working.  When I go to `localhost:3000/facility_users/facility_users/new`, i am redirected to the login page for activeadmin and told i need to login.

Comment: are you meant to be visiting `/facility_users/facility_users`?

Comment: No, I want to go to the new facility user form, so it should have '/new'.  Either way, and facility user page i go to now should not be authenticated, but they are.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is happening in your case, the code you've posted seems to be correct IMO. I'd suggest installing pry-rails and adding a binding.pry call to your controller method. Check the logs and try and figure out why it's being triggered